# Hide wordpress page completely

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I develop my first plugin, which creates some pages programatically by this method:

```
$page_id = wp_insert_post(
array(
    'comment_status' => 'close',
    'ping_status'    => 'close',
    'post_author'    => 1,
    'post_title'     => 'HSN Form',
    'post_name'      => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', trim('hsn-form'))),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    )
);
```

And I set template file for it:

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'hsn_service_form_page_template', 10, 1 );
function hsn_service_form_page_template( $page_template ){
    if ( is_page( 'hsn-form' ) ) {
        $page_template = plugin_dir_path(__DIR__) . 'service-form/form-template.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}
```

After I would like to hide it completely from wordpress dashboard, but those have to available following way:

wwww.example.com/hsn-form.

I can hide it following code from Pages menu:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'ts_hide_pages_in_wp_admin' );
function ts_hide_pages_in_wp_admin($query) {
    global $pagenow,$post_type;

    $page = get_page_by_path('hsn-form');

    if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $post_type =='page') {
        $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = array($page->ID);
    }
}
```

It's ok, but it's still available in Appereance->Menu, where you can create nav menus.

I searched for it, but I can't find complete solution for my problem:

1. My plugin has to create some pages which are available this way: www.example.com/hsn-form
2. I need to hide this pages completely from admin dashboard
3. I would like to apply templates for these pages to add some custom php code.

So If somebody should know a complete solution for it, that should be great.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

change parse_query to pre_get_posts

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a page from the admin nav menu, you can hook into the `admin_menu` action, then manipulate the global `$submenu` variable.

```php
add_action('admin_menu', function(){

    global $submenu;

    array_walk($submenu, function(&$child, $parent){

        if( $parent != 'edit.php' )
            return;
        foreach($child as $key=>$submenu){
            if( $submenu[2] == 'post-new.php' ) {
                unset($child[$key]);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In that example, we are looking for a subpage with the slug of `post-new.php` 
 underneath the top level page with the slug `edit.php`. If found, it gets altogether removed from the navigation menu.

The `$submenu[2]` part is looking for the slug element in the array. If you want to match by the submenu *name* instead, you can replace it with `$submenu[0]`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added this add action to main php file of my plugin. Is script remove submenu items from left side menu of wp dashboard? I would like to hide the page from the Pages menu and Appereance/Menu where you can build navigation menu by drag&drop. Name of my page is HSN Edit, I tried it and slug name here: $submenu[0] == 'HSN Edit' or $submenu[0] == 'hsn-edit', but this page still remain among pages.